# I'm trying to run a node.js app from python. But It is not working

Tags: python, node.js

I want to run a node.js app from python. To run the node.js app in a terminal I type "npm start".

This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "web-scraping",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
},
"author": "pupy frias",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
}
}
```

I tried with os.system from python, but it didn't work.

So, tried with this

```
from subprocess import call

    call(["node", "Offer Store\app.js"])
```

It worked, but don't find any files like views. When I run the app from any terminal (cmd, shell) it works, I don't know what is happening with this method. Please help me how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by didn't find any views? what errors are being shared

Comment: @YashKumarVerma I use MVC Design pattern (models, views and controllers) when i run `call(["node", "Offer Store\app.js"]) ` in python  it says me `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\pupy frias\Desktop\Programas\Python\Web Scraping\Offer Store\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\pupy frias\Desktop\Programas\Python\Web Scraping\Offer Store\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\pupy frias\Desktop\Programas\Python\Web Scraping\Offer Store\controllers\index.js `